# Error not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I have `FormTemplateGroup` class

```
public class FormTemplateGroup : BaseEntity, IIerarhycal<FormTemplateGroup>
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual FormTemplateGroup Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<FormTemplateGroup> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and I have some methods using `FormTemplateGroup` class

```
public FormTemplateGroup GetFormTemplateGroup(int id)
    {
        var formTemplateGroup =
            FormTemplateGroupRepository.Query().FirstOrDefault(ftg => ftg.Id == id);

        return formTemplateGroup;
    }

    public FormTemplate GetFormTemplate(int id)
    {
        var formTemplateGroup = GetFormTemplateGroup(id);

        var formTemplate =
                FormTemplateRepository.Query().FirstOrDefault(ft => ft.Group.Id == formTemplateGroup.Id);

        return formTemplate;
    }

    public bool checkForChild(IList<FormTemplateGroup> groups)
    {
        foreach (FormTemplateGroup g in groups)
        {
            if (GetFormTemplate(g.Id) != null) return false;
            if (g.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                return checkForChild(g.Children);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

but in method `checkForChild` I get an error

> Error 1   'Arg.BI.BL.Services.Dictionaries.FormTemplateGroupService.checkForChild(System.Collections.Generic.IList)':
>   not all code paths return a
>   value D:\svn\ARG_BI\Sources\trunk\Arg.BI\Arg.BI.BL\Services\Dictionaries\FormTemplateGroupService.cs  82  21  Arg.BI.BL

how to fix it?

Comment: By adding a return condition outside the foreach loop in the checkForChild method.

Comment: In your `checkForChild` method, what happen if the `groups` doesn't have any items? You should return something in that case as well!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `checkForChild`, if there's no items in `groups`, the `foreach` won't be executed. And your method will never return.

add a `return false` after the the `foreach`, like this:

```
public bool checkForChild(IList<FormTemplateGroup> groups)
{
    foreach (FormTemplateGroup g in groups)
    {
        if (GetFormTemplate(g.Id) != null) return false;
        if (g.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            return checkForChild(g.Children);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a return outside the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

if the `groups` parameter in the `CheckForChild` method is empty, there is no return statement.

Either return a boolean after the `foreach` loop, or thrown an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your `checkForChild` method should return something after the loop.
If you don't, and there are no `FormTemplateGroup`s in `groups`, the compiler won't know what to return.